# Any known issues of DXA 2.2.4 and DXA 2.2.9 with Tridion 9.6

Tags: dxa2.2

I have two web apps while one is using DXA 2.2.4 other is using DXA 2.2.9. As we are upgrading to Tridion 9.6, it will be good to know if there are any known issues of DXA 2.2.4/9 with Tridion 9.6? Or is it safe to assume that web apps developed on either DXA 2.2.4 or DXA 2.2.9 will keep working without any friction?

Also, is it advised to upgrade framework binaries for example (Sdl.Web.Tridion.dll, Sdl.Web.Mvc.dll, Sdl.Web.ModelService.dll, etc.) to a specific version for Tridion 9.6 or is it preferred to leave them to what comes as part of the framework My views are, as these binaries are part of DXA Framework so they should not be updated in isolation that implies upgrade of these binaries should not be preferred while upgrading to Tridion version 9.6.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is it Java or .NET?

Comment: It is .net based web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK - At least I did a test with Tridion 9.6 with DXA 2.2.9 OOTB for our Training Instances all working fine as expected.

I didn't see any issues. DXA CIL Libraries are forward and backward compatible. It should work.

Framework **Sdl.Web.Tridion.dll, Sdl.Web.Mvc.dll, Sdl.Web.ModelService.dll** - DLLs leave it as it's it should be working.

Currently, I'm working on the project Tridion Sites 9.5 + DXA 2.2.9 .NET so far no issues. I'm still using the standard framework version used. I only had one issue related to "*[One trust cookie policy plugin integration with DXA 2.2 .NET breaks the DXA website](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21714/one-trust-cookie-policy-plugin-integration-with-dxa-2-2-net-breaks-the-dxa-webs/21715#21715)*"

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: Also we are using XO and instant campaign module along with DXA 2.2.9. Is it safe to assume that these modules also do not have any known issue with Tridion 9.6? Please suggest.

Comment: I too tested the XO functionality with OOTB with elastic it's working fine as expected, I didn't have a chance to test the instant campaign module but tested with DXA ExperienceOptimization module it's working fine in Tridion 9.6

Comment: Thanks for the useful insights.

Comment: If that answer helped you please upvote and close this ticket.